# Matching Data in R for 5:1 Ratio

Tags: r, matching

I have matched data that I want to analyze with Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test using R-Studio, however, it is not in a 1:1 ratio. I have 5 controls for every 1 experimental case.

I made the following categories:

```
    SetNumber  CaseNumber  LungCapacity   AtRisk 
1        1           1          5           Y
2        1           2          11          N
3        1           3          8           N
4        1           4          8           N
5        1           5          7           N
6        1           6          9           N
7        2           7          6           Y
8        .           .          .           .
```

The SetNumber indicates the matched pairing, 1 positive AtRisk case for 5 negative AtRisk cases.

So far, I have this:

```
wilcox.test(LungCapacity~AtRisk)
```

Could you please help? I am not very experienced with R.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data (using `dput()`) instead of a screen shot. This will help people use your data more effectively to help you.

Comment: There are more reasons for "no plot of data" than just my laziness (though that's important to me :-): it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/).

Comment: I made those edits.